# Unit testing saga in nestjs cqrs pattern

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs, saga

We are writing unit test using jest for application and we want to cover saga in unit test. However, we are struggling to unit test saga.

While writing unit test, we are publishing InventoryEvent in inventory.saga.spec.ts file and expecting inventory() in inventory.saga.ts to be called but this published event through test file is not received by saga whereas when we publish the same event through application then event is received in saga.

Please help my to identify the issue why event published through test file is not received by saga.

The current flow of application is

1. inventory handler publish InventoryEvent
2. saga is acting as event listeners and listen for InventoryEvent and it invokes InventoryCacheCommand

Below are the code snippet

inventory.handler.ts

```
await this.eventBus.publish(new InventoryEvent(inventoryData));
```

inventory.event.ts

```
import { IEvent } from '@nestjs/cqrs';
import { InventoryStatusInterface } from '../../../interface/inventory.interface';

export class InventoryEvent implements IEvent {
  constructor(public readonly inventoryData: InventoryStatusInterface) {}
}
```

inventory.saga.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ICommand, ofType, Saga } from '@nestjs/cqrs';
import { map, Observable } from 'rxjs'
import { createLog } from '../../infrastructure/service/utils/logger';
import { InventoryCacheCommand } from '../commands/impl/inventory-cache.command';
import { InventoryEvent } from '../events/impl/inventory.event';
@Injectable()
export class InventorySaga {

private logger = createLog(InventorySaga.name);

@Saga()
inventory = (events$: Observable<any>): Observable<ICommand> => {  
    return events$.pipe(
        ofType(InventoryEvent),
        map((event: InventoryEvent) => {
            this.logger.info('received inventory event to upsert inventory cache: ',event.inventoryData);
            return new InventoryCacheCommand(event.inventoryData);
        })
    );
}
}
```

inventory.saga.spec.ts

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { InventorySaga } from './inventory.saga';
import { InventoryEvent } from '../events/impl/inventory.event';
import { CommandBus, EventBus } from '@nestjs/cqrs';
import { InventoryCacheCommand } from '../commands/impl/inventory-cache.command';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
jest.mock('../commands/impl/inventory-cache.command')

describe('InventorySaga', () => {
  let saga: InventorySaga;
  let eventBus: EventBus
  beforeEach(async () => {

    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        InventorySaga,
        EventBus,
        CommandBus
      ],
    }).compile();

    saga = module.get<InventorySaga>(InventorySaga);
    eventBus = module.get<EventBus>(EventBus)
 });

 describe('saga', () => {

   it('should publish InventoryEvent', async () => {

     const inventoryData = [
       {
         sku: 'TH4344-43-L',
         qty: 3,
       },
       {
         sku: 'TH4344-43-S',
         qty: 55,
       },
       {
         sku: 'TH4344-43-XL',
         qty: 55,
       },
     ];
     const spy = jest.spyOn(saga, 'inventory');
  
     await eventBus.publish(new InventoryEvent(inventoryData));
  
     expect(spy).toBeCalled()
   })
 })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to init your app so the eventBus and commandBus actually work. You don't have an application running.

```js
describe('InventorySaga', () => {
  let saga: InventorySaga;
  let eventBus: EventBus
  let app: INestApplication;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        InventorySaga,
        EventBus,
        CommandBus
      ],
     }).compile();

     saga = module.get<InventorySaga>(InventorySaga);
     eventBus = module.get<EventBus>(EventBus);
    

     app = moduleRef.createNestApplication<INestApplication>();

     await app.init();
   });

   afterEach(async () => {
     if (app) {
       await app.close();
     }
   });

 describe('saga', () => {//stuff})
});
```